# What is the bin folder in an express application for?

Tags: express

When creating an express application

```
express <App-name>
```

it creates a few folders and files including a bin. What is the bin folder used for exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most environments, including Windows, it is useful for setting the startup file. This startup script will execute the Node.js process that runs on the server. There is typically a `#!` on this executable file. Like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// Code to bootstrap your web application
```